# Can webargs / Marshmallow in Python modify a field, not just validate it?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow, webargs

I'm using Flask with flask-restful and [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which uses [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as its backend).  Currently I'm able to pull in fields I want with this:

```
class AddGroup(Resource):
    args = {
        'name': fields.Str(missing=None),
        'phone': fields.Str(missing=None),
    }

    @use_args(args)
    def get(self, args):
        name = args['name'].strip()
        # ... some GET-related code ...

    @use_args(args)
    def post(self, args):
        name = args['name'].strip()
        # ... some POST-related code ...
```

So far so good.  But what I'd really like to do is make sure that `args['name']` comes into the various methods ("post", "get", etc.) with whitespace already stripped, so I don't have to process each variable manually each time.  (stripping whitespace is just an example - it may be some other simple or complex transformation)

Is there a way (either by overriding the String field, defining my own field, or whatever) that will allow the `args` to be pre-processed before they arrive in the class methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `webargs` are using `marshmallow` to make schema, you can use `pre_load` or `post_load`. There is example with "slugify" a string in the docs of marshmallow:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pre_load

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    slug = fields.Str()

    @pre_load
    def slugify_name(self, in_data, **kwargs):
        in_data['slug'] = in_data['slug'].lower().strip().replace(' ', '-')
        return in_data

schema = UserSchema()
result = schema.load({'name': 'Steve', 'slug': 'Steve Loria '})
result['slug']  # => 'steve-loria'
```

You can see detailed docs here: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#pre-processing-and-post-processing-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom field class (as composition):

```
from marshmallow import fields


class Trim(fields.Field):
    def __init__(self, inner, *args, **kwargs):
        self.inner = inner
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _bind_to_schema(self, field_name, parent):
        super()._bind_to_schema(field_name, parent)
        self.inner._bind_to_schema(field_name, parent)

    def _deserialize(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        value = value.strip()
        return self.inner._deserialize(value, *args, **kwargs)

    def _serialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.inner._serialize(*args, **kwargs)
```

Usage example:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class SomeSchema(Schema):
    name = Trim(fields.String(), validate=validate.Length(max=100))
    email = Trim(fields.Email(), required=True)
```

Idea from [here](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1391#issuecomment-530357070)